# VS 2012 Intellisense broken for external DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense, sitecore

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project with a reference to a Sitecore DLL. (Sitecore is a vendor.)

For a few weeks, Intellisense has worked fine. Yesterday, after installing Patch Tuesday updates and rebooting, Intellisense no longer works for stuff in the Sitecore DLL. I don't know whether there is a correspondence.

Intellisense still works for .NET Framework stuff. E.g., if I type **string.** inside a method, I get Intellisense.

The project has a reference to the Sitecore namespace defined under **References** in Solution Explorer. Specifically, the reference is **Sitecore.Kernel**, and it comes from **Sitecore.Kernel.dll**.

If I right click on **Sitecore.Kernel** under **References** and select **View in Object Browser**, I can browse the DLL just fine. Also, my project builds fine; the project has a few **using** statements referencing parts of the Sitecore.* name space, and it uses objects in those namespaces.

If I type `using Site` and press Ctrl-space, I should see Intellisense suggesting **{} Sitecore**, but all it shows is this:

[image: Intellisense after typing 'using Site', showing no match to Sitecore stuff]

If I attempt to use Intellisense on any object in a Sitecore namespace, I get no Intellisense suggestions.

The suggestions in other areas don't work. For example:

- **Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache**: There is no **Refresh Local Cache** option. Yes, I did have a CS file open, and was editing it then.
- **Delete %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas**: There is no **ReflectedSchemas** folder there.
- **TOOLS > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings**: Did not bring back Intellisense for external stuff.
- **In Visual Studio Command Prompt, run devenv /resetuserdata**: Seems to have done something similar to the prior technique. Had no effect on Intellisense.
- **Check TOOLS > Options > Text Editor > C#**: Both **Auto list members** and **Parameter information** are checked. I think these would have been reset by the prior two steps anyway.
- **Through the VS 2012 installer (Control Panel > Uninstall a program), repair the entire VS installation.** Had no effect.
- **Remove and add back Sitecore.Kernel under References.** Had no effect.

Here's where it gets *really* weird: if I open this project remotely from a different workstation--which also has yesterday's Patch Tuesday stuff installed and rebooted--Intellisense works fine! I am referring to it using **\computername\c$...**.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Did you try removing the referenced DLL and re-adding it?

Comment: OK, it's got to be something with this project. I just made a new project, and Intellisense works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons I don't understand, I was able to get Intellisense back by creating a new project and setting it up pretty much exactly like the old project.

Comment: Are the old an new projects both using the same version of .net?

Comment: Nearly certain they were as both were greenfield projects. Please note that this question was from 1.5 years ago, so I no longer have the project handy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your web project will also need to have some Sitecore config files in the App_Config folder in the project's directory. (Not necessarily included in the project).

I've blogged about it here:-

http://www.seanholmesby.com/fixing-visual-studio-intellisense-in-sitecore-mvc-views/

Comment: Not for a non-MVC Sitecore sublayout, which was my case. You probably don't want to include **app_config** in a project as it can cause conflicts when you merge into the Sitecore product.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point about not having to include it in the project. You can still have it on the file system in the project directory, but not having it included in the project means it won't be pushed to your Sitecore instance when you publish/TDS-build.

Comment: Got it. But if it's not included in your project, it probably has no effect on Intellisense. :-)

Comment: That's what I thought too, but because Sitecore''s Web.Config is in the project, and it includes the others by path, it must resolve them that way. Also In my post I wrote about including them in the project but getting TDS to ignore them during deploy time...which is another option.

Comment: For almost all my Sitecore projects, I have no Sitecore files or references other than a reference to Sitecore.Kernel.dll.